# wireless card not accessible on hp envy ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, wireless

after trieing to fix my Bluetooth connectivity problems, i somehow managed to lose my wifi as well.
nmcli dev doesnt shows a ethernet and a loopback option but no wifi option.
sudo lshw -C network gives me 
-network UNCLAIMED
 description: network controller and 
 product rt3290 wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
 vendor ralink corp
-and a ethernet network option

some comments on other sites suggested to trie to enable it in bios, but the bios doesnt show the network option

Comment: Post the output of `lspci`

Comment: its to long, and there seems to be nothing with network, wifi or wireless in the return

Comment: What is the result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe rt2800pci` ? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: it returns nothing

Comment: would that have fixed my problem? cause its fixed and i dont know why